# LDAP, DirectoryServices c# search base for queries

Tags: c#, ldap, directoryservices

I'm trying to use an LDAP server that has the client login that apparently has to be a simple bind (with a Distinguished Name).

```
var clientEntry = new DirectoryEntry(
"LDAP://server.de",
"cn=medialibrary, ou=special users, dc=uni, dc=de",
"password",
AuthenticationTypes.None);

DirectorySearcher directorySearch = new DirectorySearcher(clientEntry, "(cn=searchuser");

SearchResult result = directorySearch.FindOne();
```

The connection via DN works fine. However the search for cn=searchuser returns no users (and no errors).

The user we are trying to search for is in path:

ou=people,dc=uni,dc=de

In the LDAP-Admin utility we can log in using the cn=medialibrary etc DN and if we then modify the search base to 
"ou=people,dc=uni-potsdam,dc=de"
and then do the search we find the cn=searchuser entry

The question is what is the equivilent to modifying the search base we can do in that utility in C# code?

(The target user is in a different branch to the default branch given by the directory entry I must originally bind to.)

I believe this original Directory url has been tried and did not work (permissions?)

LDAP://server.de/ou=people,dc=uni,dc=de

Answer (score 0):

```
string LDAPpAth = "dc=uni,dc=de"
string filter = "(cn=searchuser)"
string username = "medialibrary"
string password = "password"
DirectoryEntry startingPoint = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://"+LDAPpAth, username, password);
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(startingPoint);
searcher.Filter = filter;
```

from there you can do the searcher.findone and use the value for what you need. let me know if that works.

Comment: I have asked the customer to test this but they insist a DN is needed. I will run a batch of tests myself and include this again but for the time being can we have an example with DN as username thanks